# How to add line to geom_col() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to add a line with total number of individuals (or even better, shade the area under that line as background) to each graph being produced by:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
        
         dataset %>% 
    ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
                geom_col() +
                facet_wrap(~ office)+
                scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
                theme_classic()+
                theme(
                  strip.background = element_blank(),
                  strip.text.x = element_blank()
                )
```

I tried many versions of geom_hline but none worked.

My dataset is:

```
region   office    Nr_Individuals    total_Nr_Individuals    PovertyDecile   weighted_PovDecile
   1       A             80                 105                   2                2.5
   1       A             23                 105                   3                2.5
   1       B             2                  105                   4                4
   2       C             100                160                   1                1.5   
   2       C             60                 160                   2                1.5
   3       D             20                 70                    8                9
   3       D             50                 70                    10               9
```

what I am getting using #code4 (any thoughts?):
[image]

without gray option:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with `geom_segment()` and give a style of lollypop bars for your plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),xend=factor(PovertyDecile),yend=total_Nr_Individuals))+
  geom_point(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=total_Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile)),
             shape=21,show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~ office)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), office = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"), Nr_Individuals = c(80L, 23L, 2L, 
100L, 60L, 20L, 50L), total_Nr_Individuals = c(105L, 105L, 105L, 
160L, 160L, 70L, 70L), PovertyDecile = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
8L, 10L), weighted_PovDecile = c(2.5, 2.5, 4, 1.5, 1.5, 9, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

You can trick for segments over each bar using next code:

```
#Code 2
df %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
                    y=total_Nr_Individuals,ymin=total_Nr_Individuals,
                    ymax=total_Nr_Individuals,color=factor(PovertyDecile)))+
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ office)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

And for shaded style you can use this trick with other `geom_col()` but adjusting `alpha`:

```
#Code 3
df %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
                    y=total_Nr_Individuals,ymin=total_Nr_Individuals,
                    ymax=total_Nr_Individuals,color=factor(PovertyDecile)))+
  geom_col(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
               y=total_Nr_Individuals,
               fill=factor(PovertyDecile)),alpha=0.5) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ office)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Code 4
df %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
                    y=total_Nr_Individuals,ymin=total_Nr_Individuals,
                    ymax=total_Nr_Individuals))+
  geom_col(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
               y=total_Nr_Individuals
               ),alpha=0.6,fill='gray') +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ office)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

For continuous line:

```
#Code 5
df %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),y=Nr_Individuals,fill=factor(PovertyDecile))) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=total_Nr_Individuals))+
  geom_col(aes(x=factor(PovertyDecile),
               y=total_Nr_Individuals
  ),alpha=0.6,fill='gray') +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ office)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Duck this is quite cool - but I have many 'offices' so it can be confusing to see them all with these points... I was trying to find a way to plot a line or shade the area under the line as background for each 'office' - any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Do you mean a horizontal line for each bar?

Comment: horizontal line with total_Nr_Individuals for each 'office' , so above all bars. Ideally, I would like to shade the area under the line up to x axis.. not sure if possible?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thanks a lot. One last point, I changed #Code 2 to get a black line so I have: "scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black"))" How can I change the colour of the shades to be simply grey?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I have added an additional update for the task you look for. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Duck - unfortunately by using #code4 I am getting the image I put above in my question (I'll edit my question afterwards). Not sure what is happening, any thoughts?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Try re starting `R` it might be an issue with other package. Also compare the sample data `df` with your real data frame and test first without adding the gray color, it is so strange

Comment: I restarted R and run those 4 packages I have above. I compare my dataset with your df and it is the same except the sequence of columns. I have put above an output without adding the gray color. It is really strange

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Try adding `group=factor(PovertyDecile)` in the first `aes()` it looks like very extreme large values are in total.

Comment: Thanks Duck - it still does not work, let's forget about this. But, I noticed something. This is not creating a continuous line on top of the bars, it has space between the bars. Ideally I wanted a continuous line (that's why I tried geom_hline). Do you know how to include a continuous line?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Yeah `geom_hline()` should work! I have added an update. I hope that helps you!